# Spark performance tuning

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

Greetings of the day!!!

I have a cluster of 5 machines (1 master and 4 slaves) on which hadoop, yarn and spark is installed. I am testing the performance of my application on spark.

Here are the details

I have a 85 Mb csv file with 10 million records and the blocksize on each datanode (4 datanodes) is 128 MB with replication value 3.

I upload the file twice, the blocks distribution is following

> 1. Datanode1 - 1 Block
> 2. Datanode2 - 2 Blocks
> 3. Datanode3 - 2 Blocks
> 4. Datanode4 - 1 Block

When I submit my application (BayesNet Algorithm) on Spark it takes **approx 53 Mins** to finish.

I removed one of the machine from hadoop and spark cluster (Now my cluster is 1 master and 3 Slaves), now my hdfs block distribution looks following

> 1. Datanode1 - 2 Blocks
> 2. Datanode2 - 2 Blocks
> 3. Datanode3 - 2 Blocks

Now I have 2 blocks on each datanode, and when I submitted my application in Spark, it finished in **approx 38 mins**

> 1. Datanode1 - 3 Blocks
> 2. Datanode2 - 3 Blocks

I again removed one of the machine in hadoop and spark cluster (Now my cluster is 1 master and 2 slaves), now datanodes will have 3 blocks each.

When I submitted my application it finished in **approx 38 mins**

As we can notice adding a machine to cluster is actually increasing the execution time.

So my questions are

> 1. Theoretically adding a new machine to an existing cluster should increase the performance, why this is not true in my case?
> 2. Am I missing any configuration?
> 3. Is this because of data locality in Spark?
> 4. Or this is due to hdfs data skew?
> 5. Any pointers on how to increase the performance or execution speed?
> 6. Or is this the expected behavior?

Note : I am using Spark 1.6.2 with hadoop 2.6.0 and **I am using Spark standalone resource manager not yarn**.
Each machine is ubuntu with 16 GB ram and 4 cores.

I configured driver and worker memory to be 6 GB and Only one worker instances per node.

Code :-
First I am loading file using JavaSparkContext

```
private JavaSparkContext javaSparkContext;

SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("spark://masterIp:7077");
javaSparkContext=new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);

JavaRDD<String> rawInput = javaSparkContext.textFile("hdfs://namenodeIp/tmp/*.csv");
JavaRDD<Instance> instances = rawInput.map(new TransformStringToRDD(attributes, false));
```

Then `learnBySimulatedAnnealing`function is called

```
@Override
    public DiscreteBayesNetwork learnBySimulatedAnnealing(double maxNumberOfParents, double prior, boolean isCausal, int classIndex,
            double initTemperature, int maxIterations, double temperatureStep) {

        JavaRDD<org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint> rddLabeledPoints = getLabeledPointRddFromJavaRddInstances(instances,
                classIndex);
        List<Map<String, List<String>>> format = new ArrayList<>(attributes.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < attributes.size(); i++) {
            Map<String, List<String>> attrNameAndValues = new HashMap<>();
            Attribute attr = attributes.get(i);
            List<Value> allNominalVals = attr.getAllNominalValues();
            List<String> attrValNames = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int j = 0; j < allNominalVals.size(); j++) {
                attrValNames.add(allNominalVals.get(j).getName());
            }
            attrNameAndValues.put(attr.getName(), attrValNames);
            format.add(attrNameAndValues);
        }
        BayesianBeliefNetwork nw = SimulatedAnnealing.learnNetwork(rddLabeledPoints, maxNumberOfParents, prior, false, classIndex, format,
                initTemperature, maxIterations, temperatureStep, ScoringType.ENTROPY());
        System.out.println(nw.treeDescription(format));

        JavaBayesianBeliefNetwork network = BayesianBeliefNetwork.getJavaBayesianBeliefNetwork(nw);
        DiscreteBayesNetwork discreteBayesNetwork = null;
        discreteBayesNetwork = ConversionUtilities.convertJavaBayesianBeliefNetworkToDiscreteBayesNetwork(network, attributes, format,
                (int) maxNumberOfParents, prior, isCausal, classIndex);
        return discreteBayesNetwork;
    }

/**Parses data from JavaRDD<Instance> to RDD<org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector>.
 * @param JavaRDD<Instance>
 * @return RDD<org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector>
 */
public static JavaRDD<org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint> getLabeledPointRddFromJavaRddInstances(
        JavaRDD<Instance> rddInstances, int classIndex){

    // Load and parse data
    JavaRDD<org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint> parsedData = 
            rddInstances.map(new Function<Instance, org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint>() {
                public org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint call(Instance inst) {
                    double[] values = new double[inst.getValues().size() -1];
                    double label = Double.NaN;
                    for (int numValue = 0; numValue < inst.getValues().size(); numValue++) {
                        double val = inst.getValue(numValue).getNumericValueAsDouble();
                        if(numValue != classIndex){
                            values[numValue] = val;
                        }
                        else{
                            label = val;
                        }
                    }

                    Vector featureVals = Vectors.dense(values);
                    LabeledPoint lb = new LabeledPoint(label, featureVals);
                    return lb;
                }
            });
    parsedData.cache();
    return parsedData;
}
```

In the above code the line `SimulatedAnnealing.learnNetwork` (which is present in `learnBySimulatedAnnealing`function above) is the main entry point to the algorithm which is implemented in `SimulatedAnnealing.scala` and other required functions is implemented in `BayesianNetAlgorithm.scala`, As the lines of code is more I am providing the link to [git hub](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3ee04ecd42c7fc316be106eafd33353b) where other required code is present.

Comment: _Theoretically adding a new machine to an existing cluster should increase the performance_ - no. It may increase performance if and only if cost of increasing distribution can be amortized by improved IO throughput and increased parallelism. You haven't shown your code but in general __with 85MB Spark doesn't make sense at all__.

Comment: @zero323 I have uploaded the file twice, so basically I am running spark on 170 Mb file. So what is the minimum file size you recommend? I will generate that file and test Spark performance.

Comment: All things being equal having somewhere between 64-256MB of data per partitions is a good idea with number of partitions  larger than total number of executor threads. Otherwise there is a good chance the only thing you'll observe is scheduling latency and shuffles.

Comment: @zero323 Okay I will try that out and let you know the results by tomorrow. I am launching the spark job through `SparkLauncher`, and I have a lot of classes in my project, If you want I can show the code of my algorithm's train function.

Comment: Well, it could provide some additional insights but if you don't observe serious skew or some data locality issue then I don't think there is anything more going or here.

Comment: Have you monitored the CPU usage during the job? If it is low, you may consider a coalesce operation on the rawInput rdd to take it down to a single (1) partition.

Comment: @JMaurer No I haven't monitored the CPU usage, I will do that and also the other suggestion given by zero323, but I can let you guys know the outcome by tomorrow afternoon IST.

Comment: @zero323 I ran the spark application on 8.4 GB file which corresponds to approx 67 blocks in hdfs with 4 executors of 2 cores and 4 GB memory, when I looked up the web ui of Jobs. one stage is taking around 3 min of time this is because it executing entire DAG(Loading data from file etc) at that point and locality level for that stage is ANY. This is happening even though I am caching the rdd `parsedData.cache()`(This is in above code). Attaching [Image](http://imgur.com/a/ePCm8) for reference.

Comment: @JMaurer I monitored the CPU usage, it was high, meaning CPU utilization was around 85% to 95%.

Comment: hi @Ravikumar, do you remember how you were able to solve this problem? I am also facing a similar issue, my spark job is taking around 1hr to process just ~120MB of data. My transformation includes around 9 joins, out of which only one left side table has ~120 MB of data and the other right side tables are very small (like in few KBs.